# How to design data driven dependent scenarios testing?

Tags: automated-tests, karate

I read its NOT best practice to write dependent test scenarios.
But what if an application  is heavily data-driven and manipulates (creates, multiple update flows, logically deletes) data. Basically, we want to minimize:

1. Test data creation for each dependent scenario (ex. updates need creation of data first)
2. re-execution of steps
3. Overall test suite execution time

Question: In order to control the execution of threads, can I can extend Karate core classes which handles @parallel=false and add custom code which considers 'Depends on Scenario' ? Is there a better/alternate design? Please suggest.

Example:

- Scenario1 : Create T1, T2  [Parallel]
- Scenario2 : Create T3       [Parallel]
- Scenario3 : Create R1(relationship between T1 and T2)which updates
  T1, T2 [Sequential: wait until 1]
- Scenario4 : Create R2(relationship between T1 and T3) which updates
  T1, T3 [Sequential:wait until 1,2]
- Scenario5 : Delete R1 which updates T1,T2 [Sequential: wait until
  1,3]
- Scenario6 : Delete T1 which deletes R1,R2  [Sequential: wait until
  1,4,5]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no "magic" you have to either:

a) write "flows" that set up data at the start (this is what a `Background` is for) and test all the expected conditions

b) write tests that are "smart" and are immune to the starting state of the database. for example, do a GET, see how many customers already exist, and then calculate expected count. but this can be affected by parallel threads unless each thread is designed to work on a different set of customers (partition by e.g. organization)

As a reminder, read this: https://github.com/intuit/karate#script-structure

[image]

Comment: I get the options that Karate's provides out of the box with Background, call, callonce which aids to setup the data. And to your point b) above, what I am looking for is to have some "control" over the execution of scenarios while still running in parallel. Ex. Scenario3 waits until Secnario1 is complete..example from my original post above

Comment: I know Karate out-of-box doesn't provide this control, but can I extend Karate-core classes (com.intuit.karate.core.FeatureExecutionUnit.java etc)and implement the controlling logic between scenarios?

Comment: @jyohas assume that my answer is *NO* - but it really depends on your proficiency in java :) any other questions ?

Comment: We did something similar for 'controlling the scenarios execution'  leveraging java.util.concurrent.Phaser but that was implemented on top of Cucumber.  But now, we like ( as it offers all that good stuff out of the box for our REST API microservices testing) Karate and wanted to go forward with it except trying to see if we can do this 'contrl scenario execution' and use it only as needed. Any insights in to how/what classes can be extended/overridden would help. Thanks

Comment: @jyohas no I discourage that and also don't have the time to give you those insights. the right thing to do is use Karate the way it is - it is simple. if you have scenarios that should  not clash, put them in the same feature and use the `@parallel=false` tag. else the next best right thing to do is contribute changes to Karate to make it work for you - but IMO it is highly unlikely you have some "special" situation that other teams don't have. for that you need to understand the code, so you can try. all the best

Comment: OK; yes the alternatives for sequencing I was thinking was to organize feature files and scenarios in such way so that we can use @parallel=false and also call(*.feature) from within a scenario.